# Unable to get proper boolean output from method (Java)

Tags: java, methods, boolean, readfile

I have written a boolean method which can be called upon to read information from a file.  If certain exceptions are thrown, the method should return the boolean value "false."  If not, it should return the value "true".  However, the method always returns the value "true" no matter what.  The actual file being read has a number in the first line (representing week number), and the rest of the lines consist of treatment information for one patient for each line.  My code is as follows:

```
public boolean readTreatmentsFromFile(String filename) {
  boolean value = true;
  try {
    FileReader textFileReader = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(textFileReader);

    System.out.println("READING TREATMENTS FROM FILE: " + filename);

    int week = Integer.parseInt(textReader.readLine());

    if (week != weekNumber) {
      throw new ArithmeticException(); 
    }

    String post = textReader.readLine();

    while(post != null) {
      addPost(post);
      if (!addPost(post))
        value = false;
      post = textReader.readLine();
    }
    textReader.close();
  }
  catch (ArithmeticException exception) {
    System.out.println("Invalid week number in the file: " + filename);
    value = false;
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
    System.out.print("The file cannot be located");
    value = false;
  }
  catch (IOException exception) {
    System.out.print("Cannot read the file:" + filename);
    value = false;
  }

  return value;
}
```

Any information as to how I should alter the code in order for it to give me a proper boolean result will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are any of the exceptions being thrown?

Comment: Actually, now that I look at output, I see that the exception being thrown is actually from the addPost-method, which I use in the while-loop.  Let me look closer at my code, and see if I can figure this out.

Comment: Hi.  I now tried to account for the fact that an Exception might also be thrown by the method addPost (which is a method which adds the post to an array, and which also returns a boolean value).  Now, I get the proper boolean output.  However, for some reason, the program prints out the Exception message associated with this method twice.  Any idea on what may cause this?

Comment: You either call the method twice, or print the message twice, perhaps from inside `addPost()`?

Comment: *'If certain exceptions are thrown, the method should return the boolean value "false."'*  For better quality information, don't catch the exceptions within the method.  And as to statements like.. `System.out.print("Cannot read the file:" + filename);` 1) Use `System.err` for error information 2) `exception.printStackTrace();` is not only shorter to type, but more informative at run-time.

Comment: Dave: Thanks for the tip.  I don't think there is anything wrong with the addPost-method.  The exception is only printed twice as long as I have the if (!addPost(post))
            value = false;                                         If remove this from the code, the exception is only printed once.

Comment: Andrew:  Thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately, I have not yet learned about system.err.  But I will certainly keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: Well, I found out that if I just remove the addPost(post), everything runs smoothly.  Thus, in the while-loop it starts right off with if(!addPost(post)).  So I think it is ok now.  I really appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider this: return a variable 'result', which defaults to false; set it to true only when successful. See below (note that I have not debugged your code per se):

```
public boolean readTreatmentsFromFile(String filename) {
    boolean result = false; // pessimistic default

        try {
            FileReader textFileReader = new FileReader(filename);
            BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(textFileReader);

            System.out.println("READING TREATMENTS FROM FILE: " + filename);

            int week = Integer.parseInt(textReader.readLine());

            if (week != weekNumber) {
                throw new ArithmeticException(); 
            }

            String post = textReader.readLine();

            while(post != null) {
                addPost(post);
                post = textReader.readLine();
            }
            textReader.close();
            result = true;  // SUCCESS!
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException exception) {
            System.out.println("Invalid week number in the file: " + filename);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.print("The file cannot be located");
        }
        catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.print("Cannot read the file:" + filename);
        }

        return result;
    }
```